# asp:literal with img not aligning

Tags: asp.net, image

I am trying to give a padding to left space in the image in the asp:literal

```
 <asp:Literal ID="litPageHeader" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="litPageHeaderResource1"
            Text='<img style="padding-left:50px;" src="images/en/HdrFtr/sh-traveldetails.gif" alt=" MY Travel Details"  />' />
```

but when i check the source code for the page, i am getting

```
<img alt="Your Travel Details" src="images/en/HdrFtr/sh-traveldetails.gif">
```

the padding effect is not coming   ..  Is there anything missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, not 100% sure why that's happening.  I'd bet is has something to do with some weird way the single and double quotes are being interpreted.

However, I know for sure that setting the Text property in the code behind during some page event like Page_Load() would work.  I've already used code similar to this today:

```
protected void Page_load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    litPageHeader.Text = "<img style=\"padding-left:50px;\" src=\"images/en/HdrFtr/sh-traveldetails.gif\" alt=\" MY Travel Details\"  />";
}
```

Comment: I was able to solve it by adding the text to resource file and using that